# javascript syntax with escaping slash

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've noticed some sites use this method as a backup source if Google's hosted jquery fails to load. I copied it too, and am now curious about the syntax:

```
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
```

As I understand it, if jQuery is false or undefined, then write out a script to load jquery locally.

What I'm unsure of is, what is the point of the `\` in the closing script tag? what is there to escape?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to escape the '/' character in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170609/why-do-i-need-to-escape-the-character-in-javascript) and [What's <\/script> for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188321/whats-script-for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping the whole `</script>` tag itself. This is because, many of the older browsers think that the script gets ended here:

```
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>');
-----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

That point becomes the end of the original `<script>` tag!