# Using && or || in CDN fallback - is there a difference?

Tags: jquery, cdn, fallback

This is a quick question, that will probably immediately mark me as a newbie, but here goes :-)

When looking at code samples, that include a fallback for using a jquery cdn, I see too very similar approaches using either && or ||:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

and

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Now, my question is simply: Is there a difference (other than personal preference and sense of readability) between the two?

Comment: I think those are used for shorthand coding.. (I don't know much about it)

Comment: They are the same (in this case), if you also take the `!` at the beginning into account (or the lack thereof).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially these two scripts perform the same function.  They check if jQuery was loaded by the CDN and if not they fall back to a local copy.  The only difference is the way the check is performed.

**First Script**

```
window.jQuery || 
  document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')
```

If jQuery fails to load then `window.jQuery` will be `undefined` or `false` causing the second portion of the boolean expression to be evaluated since an `||` (or operator) is used, making the local copy of the script load.  This is basic `or` logic, since an `||` operator will evaluate each condition when the preceding condition is false.

**Second Script**

```
!window.jQuery && 
       document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')
```

This script is just negating the check for jQuery, `!window.jQuery`, so if jQuery is `undefined`, which is equivalent to `false`(and when negated == to true) it will evaluate the second portion of the boolean expression, causing the local copy to be loaded.  If jQuery is loaded the first part of the boolean expression is equivalent to false when negated, causing the second portion of the expression not be evaluated.

Here is a small script example of how the boolean logic plays out:

```
!false && alert("First condition is true evaluate me");

false || alert("First condition is false evaluate me");

false && alert("I am never evaluated since first condition is false, entire condition is false.");

true || alert("I am never evaluated since first condition is true, entire condition is true");
```

**Boolean Script Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbLfB/

Comment: As I thought then :-) And thank you for really spelling it out in a nice detailed explanation!

Comment: @KimChristensen Glad I can help. You will see this type of logic in a lot of javascript.

Comment: @KevinBowersox why does the script tage include \/ ? ie. <\/script>

Comment: @agconti See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170609/why-do-i-need-to-escape-the-character-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can understand the explanation below:

`||` searches for true (*it stops searching if it finds true, else false*)

```
true  || false   --> true  (runs first  statement)
false || true    --> true  (runs second statement)
true  || true    --> true  (runs first  statement)
false || false   --> false (runs second statement)
```

---

`&&` goes to next statement if the current statement is `true` (*in sequence*)

```
true  && false   --> false (runs  second   statement)
false && true    --> false (stops at first statement)
true  && true    --> true  (runs  second   statement)
false && false   --> false (stops at first statement)
```

PS: `null` and `undefined` also comes in to account of `false`.