# How to play video in new (blank) window?

Tags: javascript, html, video, attributes, steam

**Hi guys,**
I'running on wordpress
I made this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQxkx.png
When I click on ''Click here to play the video clip'' it open a new (blank) window)
in HTML editor I wrote code: 


```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('','video','top=50, left=50, width=280, height=257, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,');">Click here to play the video clip</a>
```

But, I don't know how to implent this code into this blank space:


```
<script src='http://hqq.tv/player/hash.php?hash=244206211243244205241239213235211241'></script><script src='http://hqq.tv/player/script.php?width=720&height=450'>
```

I want this blank window will be looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxvvM.png

Have you any solutions?

Thanks for help..
Have a nice day ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `window.open('',` part you missed the first important part: the URL you should render. What you can do is, within your same web project, you can either:

a) Create a new, dynamic URL where you can pass the Video ID or something that let's you reference a single video and open that dynamic URL.

or, if you don't have a backend language, then you can...

b) Modify the content of the `about:blank` page you just opened by creating the popup, adding the HTML code inside and opening it. You'll still have an `about:blank` URL but you'll be actually seeing whatever content you put there. To do so, you should...

```
// Source: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/write-content-dynamic-javascript-popup/

var w = window.open('', '', 'width=400,height=400');
w.document.write('HTML content goes here, such as your script from hqq.tv');
w.document.close();
```

And modify the script accordingly.

PS: Be aware that, in order to write a `script` tag with Javascript, you'll have to split the tag in order to render it. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170633/1012139) to see the problem and solution.

Comment: Thank for help :) works fine! ... i implented this code 
(in next response)
<br>
this works! :) you can see it on http://maturita.info/logo/ ..it is different code from different webplayer with `<iframe>`, but i dont know how can I implement the code with `<script>`? I have read this topic(in link from you)...When I paste there tag with `<script>` nothing happens, the window does not open... I tried everything :(<br>

Thanks for help...

Comment: `<script>
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=800');
w.document.write('<IFRAME SRC="http://youwatch.org/embed-1qih5palet6n.html" FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="NO" allowfullscreen="true" WIDTH=750 HEIGHT=50></IFRAME>');
w.document.close();
</script>`

Comment: That's great! I did answer your second problem as well, in the "PS" part. Essentially is, since you're writing Javascript inside Javascript, the final `<script>` tag is being read and forces the code to terminate, so you need to write it using a trick. Like I told you in the solution, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2170633/1012139) to learn how to do that. 

And if the solution worked for you, please accept it as well marking it with the tick icon below the vote options.

Comment: I have have solution, I wrote this: 
`<script src='http://hqq.tv/player/hash.php?hash=244206211243244205241239213235211241'></script><script src='http://hqq.tv/player/script.php?width=720&height=450'>>\x3C/script>`
This I think, will works, but when I refresh page, the popup window do not open. The tag is valid(I check it in simple page and the video was here).
I don't know ... 
Is there any solution how to open the window no automatically, but for example: click on link and open after click?

Comment: Just wire the creation process to a function. [Take a look at this example using jQuery](https://jsbin.com/widutuneyi/edit?html,output).